# Require a fast function that ascends and then descends, using bitwise operation

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I need an integer-valued function that returns an ascending sequence until it reaches a given maximum value, then descends again. I call it a Ziggurat:

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 6 5 4 3 2 1 0

The steps are all by one. The maximum value (in the middle of the sequence) must appear twice. Out side the range zero to 2* max, I don't care what happens.

I want the function to be fast - no branching. I prefer bitwise operations.

As an example of what will not work, here is my Pyramid function, and my implementation of absolute value:

```
private static readonly int LONG_ABS_MASK_SHIFT = sizeof(long) * 8 - 1;

/// <summary>
/// Compute the Absolute value of a long without branching.
/// 
/// Note: This will deviate from Math.Abs for Int64.MinValue, where the .NET library would throw an exception.
/// The most negative number cannot be made positive.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="v">Number to transform.</param>
/// <returns>Absolute value of v.</returns>
public static long Abs(this long v)
{
    long mask = v >> LONG_ABS_MASK_SHIFT;
    return (v ^ mask) - mask;
}

public static long Pyramid(this long N, long max)
{
    return max - (max - N).Abs();
}
```

This Pyramid function creates sequences like 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1 0

Notice that the middle number occurs only once.

I had an idea of storing a lookup table as consecutive blocks of bits inside a long or a BigInteger and shifting and masking them out, but that takes up too much memory for a long series. It uses very few instructions, though.

Comment: FYI-- There is NO NEED for `LONG_ABS_MASK_SHIFT`. Use `-1`. MSDN: *If the first operand is a long or ulong (64-bit quantity), the shift count is given by the low-order six bits of the second operand (second operand & 0x3f).* (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt18et0d.aspx)

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping there was a way around that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function:

```
public static long Ziggurat(this long N, long max)
{
  N = max - N;
  return max - (N ^ N >> -1);
}
```

There are no loops, tests, or branches. Only four operations are required; two are bitwise.

---

However, there is a problem with your question. You specify an output of:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

This sequence has 14 elements. However, you also specify the range of the function as "zero to 2* max" which only has 13 elements! I presume a range of zero to `2 * max + 1` is acceptable then.

And, here is a console based test:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  long max = 6;
  for (long i = 0; i <= 2 * max + 1; i++)
  {
    Console.Write("{0} ", i.Ziggurat(max));
  }
}
```

And the output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

---

The line `N = max - N` causes the input value to count down from the maximum value and into the negative side of the number line such that the range `0 through 13` becomes `6 through -7`.

Note the following:

- The bitwise complement of `-1` is `0` (~11111111 = 00000000).
- The bitwise complement of `-7` is `6` (~11111001 = 00000110).

Thus, if we count from `6` to `-7` and complement all negative values, we obtain this sequence which includes two zeroes:

```
6 5 4 3 2 1 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

The sub-expression `N ^ N >> -1` in the second line complements `N`, but only when `N` is negative.

The remaining part of the expression in the second line `max - …` inverts the sequence above into the desired output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

∎

Comment: You noticed that I can't count! Yes, I specified the range incorrectly. I am accepting this answer. Despite days of reading up on bit-shifting tricks, the simplest solutions elude me. Good job!

Comment: @PaulChernoch Fortunately, you already revealed the important clues: (1) Right shifts perform *sign extending* which allows `x ^ x >> -1` to yield either `x` or the complement of `x`, if `x` is negative. (2) The need for two zeroes (`max - x`) in the middle of the sequence. BOTH of these clues SCREAM OUT "one's complement" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) which you should read about. Normally, negative numbers are represented using two's complement (which you should also read about), but the former often has advantages in bitwise/machine language situations. Best!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public static long Pyramid2(this long N, long max)
{
    return N.Pyramid(max + 1) + ((max - N) >> -1);
}
```

*Result:*

0
1
2
3
4
5
6
6
5
4
3
2
1
0

---

The result is obtained as follows:

```
                  \ N=0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
  N.Pyramid(6 + 1)    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0 -1 -2 -3 -4
+ ((max - N) >> -1)   0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
=                     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  6  5  4  3  2  1  0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5
```

*Pyramid*  is the original *Pyramid* method defined in the question.

Comment: Can you please explain the undefined `Pyramid` function? And how this produces the result?

Comment: Post edit: Indeed, that works. But do you think adding a "fix" to non-working code is the best approach? This is the function that you now have if we expand all the operations in the three functions: `(max + 1) - ((((max + 1) - N) ^ (((max + 1) - N) >> -1)) - (((max + 1) - N) >> -1)) + ((max - N) >> -1)`. Can this expression be called 'fast'? Can it be simplified?

Comment: Upvote for being first to point out the rightshift of -1 and the good explanation. Didn't think that was allowed, much less know what it would do.

Comment: @KevinP.Rice: It's often easier to adjust something you already have than building something new. I'm very impressed by the solution you came up with. That's why I upvoted it.

Comment: @dtb I can agree with that, but you often build a kludge when doing so, thus it is best to limit that to quick work-arounds or bug fixes. In this instance, the requirement for 'fast' precludes makeshift solutions, IMHO. Good recognition of the issue, however. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static IEnumerable<long> getPyramid(long maxValue)
{
    for(long i = 0; i <= maxValue; i++)
    {
        yield return i;
    }

    for(long i = maxValue; i >=0; i--)
    {
        yield return i;
    }
}
```

One could probably work up the whole thing with `Concat` `Enumerable.Range` and possibly a select/reverse or something like that, but it would probably be slightly less efficient since I don't know of a trivial way of having it count down.  Reverse would be more "work" than the yielding for loop, and a select (that did maxvalue minus the current iteration of the `Enumerable.Range`) would be doing a bunch of extra arithmetic, all to avoid a few lines of code.

i.e.:

```
public static IEnumerable<long getPyramid(long maxValue)
{
  return Enumerable.Range(0, maxValue)
  .Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, maxValue).Select(num => maxValue - num));
}
```

Comment: I did consider using enumerators, but the for loop has conditional branches and jumps for the loop counter tests. However, when I call the function, I will likely be in a loop of some kind, so if that loop does not clash with this one, I could combine them into one iterator. When I am further along with my application I will know.

Comment: You have a sequence; your specs call that out quite a lot.  An Enumerator **is** a sequence.  Unless you happen to need the random access into the sequence, I suggest finding out how to make something like this fit into your model.  If you are having trouble doing that you can post the surrounding context and we can have a look at it.

Comment: Though your first answer is good, I don't feel this solution addresses the question in regards to bitwise operations (though the question is poorly defined). And as a matter of personal comment, I find LINQ is abusively and impulsively overused in the programming community to collapse a few lines of high performance code into one line of incredible sub-performing code bloat.

Comment: @KevinP.Rice I proposed this solution precicely because I felt that the OPs attempt to use bit shifting operators/etc. was not the right approach to take to solving his overall problem (which was still described in the OP itself).  He needs a solution that provides a sequence, but he's expecting a solution that only provides a single value based on an index into that sequence.  Returning an IEnumerable is the best representation of the purpose of this function so long as there isn't a compelling need to get at it by index.

Comment: As for performance, both of these methods will perform quite well.  Some of the bit shifting solutions provided are going to be doing a comparable amount of work; I doubt you'll see a significant performance different while these solutions are *far* more readable.

Comment: @KevinP.Rice I ran a few tests, my function was ~20% slower than yours for several various ranges/iterations.  Personally, since it's so fast in either case I'd go with the readable function since a 20% gain of such a quick function isn't really worth the mess of bitwise logic, unless there really was a compelling reason to need the performance.

Comment: @Servy Good work in testing! The odd and specific requirements in this question suggest this is some sort of homework assignment or learning exercise. Thus, I pursued the question on its face. Any `for` loop includes a test and a branch which is prohibited by the question. The bitwise solution can be implemented in around five or six machine instructions which would well outperform any C# implementation. Exploring the power of bit level manipulation is extremely valuable to understanding microcontrollers and environments where robust languages and CPU resources are not available.

Comment: @KevinP.Rice Don't get me wrong, I recognize the important of understanding an utilizing bitwise operations *when in an appropriate context*.  It didn't appear to me that this was such a context, so I avoided using them.  I do agree that too few programmers have a good understanding of them and don't use them effectively.  Like everything else, it's one tool of many powerful tools; the good programmer is the one that uses the best tool for each task.

Comment: @Servy I cut my teeth toggling binary machine instructions into a system with 256 bytes of RAM (http://www.incolor.com/bill_r/elf/html/elf-1-33.htm). You didn't dare waste a whopping 25 bytes to implement this problem. Similar limitations still exist in today's microcontrollers. I *cringe* when massive hammers are thrown at simple problems (i.e., `x.Pow(2)` instead of `x << 1`). When someone proclaims their LINQ one-liner to be "much better" when they just linked in two massive APIs I die inside. A player piano on stage in place of a concert pianist only sometimes makes a good programmer. :)